Why would a laptop turn off after 15 seconds?
I have a laptop that my late father bought for us. Today, after owning it for about 6-7 years, it won't turn on. Or rather, it turns on, and after 15 seconds, it turns off.
The screen never comes on in that time. Even though I worked in IT for 5 years (a while ago, admittedly), I've never seen this, nor learned any skills on even beginning to diagnose.
Any and all tips most welcome. It may be old, but in terms of spec, even something equivalent, today, would be way more than we can afford at the moment (no sob story, I promise), and would disrupt our life significantly so I want to put due diligence in repairing before considering replacing. Especially given that my PC is currently going through its own problems at the moment...
It is an AORUS laptop, with a GTX 1080 in it. I'm not really sure what other specs are relevant. I just want to figure out why it's immediately going off.

Left unplugged overnight. Now it is coming on and staying on but nothing happens to the screen, and the USBs don't power up

Maybe the battery is no longer good. Have you tried to remove it and use the laptop directly from the mains?

@ReddyLutonadio you are a good person for responding so quick, I am floored. Unfortunately, AORUS are way too posh to allow such a peasant thing as "removing a battery". The battery died a LONG time ago and we've been stuck with only ever powering it from mains...

Its possible the cooler died. So the laptop shuts down to prevent the CPU from blowing up. There's no image because the power on self test fails.

Other thing to check is the classic capacitors.  Those used to be the first parts dying in many electronics. Sadly that would means actually opening the laptop and looking for misformed/swollen capacitors. So not the first thing people want to test. :(

@Hennes thanks and thanks LPChip, will give it ago

The battery not being removable is a minor issue. You should still be able to open the computer up and disconnect the battery to achieve the same result. A fully dead battery could have impact on the system similar to what you describe, even when the device is connected to main power. But, like LPchip mentions, it could also be a cooling issue. You have two good suggestions to follow. Report back as you learn more.
